# How to show how much functions register in netfilter hooks？

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How to show how much function is registered on one netfilter hook？

Is Linux provide proc interface to show this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a standard way.

It's quite easy to do in code, because the `nf_hooks` matrix is exported.
So a simple `list_for_each(i, &nf_hooks[reg->pf][reg->hooknum])n++` loop would count them.

Note that it isn't 100% safe, because it doesn't take the lock protecting the list. But for experimental purposes, and if you don't run it while registering/unregistering locks, it should be OK.

Comment: Yes, I know this way can meet what I needed. But why Linux kernel do not provide this proc interface. It will be benefit for debug. Thx!

Comment: Linux doesn't provide it, this is clear. Why? Probably because nobody thought it's worth the effort. There are many things that could be exported, and are not.